# Elasticsearch - Get not found buckets in aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm making a search with different aggregations filters. Like the image below:
[image: without clicked]
[image: with a selected checkbox]

When a user check a checkbox i launch query and filter the whole data_set and i want my aggregations result the non found aggregate.

Like that i'm able to display on the filter

1. Picture1: projet count 1
2. Picture2 projet disappears

but i want to be able from my elastisearch query to get the **whole 0 match for aggregate**.

I can paste my elasticsearch query if necessery.

Any help of the keyword i need to check in the ES documentation or a trick to do that will be a new breathe for me.

Thanks

elasticsearch: 6.3

UPDATE

QUERY ES

```
 "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [],
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [],
                        "should": []
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "highlight": {
            "fields": {
                "numberStr": { "type": "plain" },
                "natureOfRequest": { "type": "plain" }
            }
        },
        'aggs': {
            'all_aggs': {
                'global': {},
                "aggs": {
                    "orderType": {
                        "filter": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [],
                                "should": []
                            }
                        },
                        "aggregations": {
                            "filtered_orderType": {
                                "terms": { "field": "orderType.keyword" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'site': {
                        "filter": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [],
                                "should": []
                            }
                        },
                        "aggregations": {
                            "filtered_site": {
                                "terms": { "field": "site.name.keyword" },
                                "aggs": {
                                    "data": {
                                        "top_hits": {
                                            "_source": {
                                                "includes": ["site.name", "site._id"]
                                            },
                                            "size": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you share your current query?

Comment: shared to my initial post